# What means this type data?

Tags: c

I see this type data in code program. But I don't know this type data. What means this type of data?

```
(uint16_t)~0U
```

Comment: ok.. first of all.. pick a language.

Comment: Where you saw this ? First time I'm seeing on SO.

Comment: C#, java, c and C++ - cool.

Comment: What's with the tags?

Comment: What is your question about ('what means type data?'), the `(uint16_t)` part of the `~0U` part?

Comment: in tag C. what means ~0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(uint16_t) ~ 0 U
     ^     ^ ^ ^
     |     | | |____ unsigned constant
     |     | |______ the number 0
     |     |________ bitwise not operator
     |______________ casting to 16 bits integer
```

As a result you get a 0xffff

Answer (score 0):

**uint16_t** is just a 16-bit unsigned integer.

```
typedef unsigned int uint16_t
```

on platforms where `int` is a 16-bit integer.

Comment: On many platforms `int` is a 32-bit integer, and `uint16_t` is defined as `unsigned short`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(uint16_t)~0U
```

`uint16_t` in `c/c++` is 16-bit Unsigned Integer, here it's for casting to it.

`~0` means it's flipping 000000000 to 1111111111

`U` is unsigned constant

You can see how to use it in the below example:

```
static T lanczos_sum(const T& z)
   {
      static const BOOST_MATH_INT_TABLE_TYPE(T, boost::uint16_t) denom[6] = {
         static_cast<boost::uint16_t>(0u),
         static_cast<boost::uint16_t>(24u),
         static_cast<boost::uint16_t>(50u),
         static_cast<boost::uint16_t>(35u),
         static_cast<boost::uint16_t>(10u),
         static_cast<boost::uint16_t>(1u)
      };
      return boost::math::tools::evaluate_rational(num, denom, z);
   }
```